# Oldest process of users in who

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, ps

How to show the oldest process of each user listed in the command `who`?
I've tried using the command

```
ps -u $user --sort +start_time
```

but couldn't find a way to filter the users and extract the PID from there.
The output should be something like like:

```
user1 oldestprocessPID 

user2 oldestprocessPID
```

Linux version: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far? The whole thing, even if it doesn't work yet.

Comment: $USER not $user.

Comment: @nobody Can you explain this incomprehensible, and probably wrong, comment?

Comment: 1. Please post the sample output you get using the command you posted. 2. Which Linux/UNIX are you on? 3. Can you pipe the output of that command to a file and sort the columns in it?

Answer (score 2):

The oldest PID given some username `user` can be had by

```
pgrep -U user -o
```

where `-o` is responsible for returning the oldest PID (see the `pgrep` manual).

To run this for all users that are currently logged on:

```
users | tr ' ' '\n' |
while read user; do
    printf '%s %d\n' "$user" "$(pgrep -U "$user" -o)"
done
```

This calls the `users` utility which outputs the currently logged on users in a single line. The `tr` changes the spaces between the usernames into newlines, and the loop reads these one by one into the variable `user`.  For each username, `pgrep -U "$user" -o` is called.  The output of this is used as an argument to `printf` to format the resulting line for this particular user.

With shells whose `read` utility can read until a delimiter with `-d` (e.g. `zsh` and `bash`), you may get rid of the `tr` like so:

```
users |
while read -d ' ' user; do
    printf '%s %d\n' "$user" "$(pgrep -U "$user" -o)"
done
```